# Write hex dump of raw binary bytes in Python 3 in Windows

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in a specified number of bytes from an arbitrary file and output it as a string of bytes. For now I'm just trying to output to stdout but eventually I'm going to want a string of bytes that I can do byte-level comparisons with. The thing is that I cannot for the life of me get Python to output the raw binary values without interpreting them as ASCII.

Here is my code.

```
import sys, os, msvcrt

msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

bde_file_offset = int(sys.argv[1])
bde_file_numbytes = int(sys.argv[2])

for x in range(3, len(sys.argv)):
  bde_file = open(str(sys.argv[x]),"rb")
  bde_file.seek(bde_file_offset)
  bde_file_bytestring = bde_file.read(bde_file_numbytes)
  sys.stdout.buffer.write(bde_file_bytestring)
  bde_file.close()
```

I did some research on this question before asking and I found three potential solutions, none of which have worked. I've tried to run the Python interpreter with -u. I've tried to use this msvcrt.setmode function and I've tried using sys.stdout.buffer.write. I've even tried all of them at once! Nothing works.

The test file that I'm using for this is a text file with ABCDEFG. I don't want it to output ABCDEFG though, I want it to output 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 like the binary view in a hex editor. How can I make this happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the words you are using mean what you think they mean :P

you are indeed seeing the raw bytes string...if your terminal knows how to render a byte it will... ... what you are asking for is the ascii hex dump.

```
def hex_dump(my_string):
    return " ".join(map("{0:0>2X}".format,map(ord,my_string)))

my_string = "ABCDE"
print(hex_dump(my_string))
```

if you just want the `ord`inal values

```
ordinal_values = map(ord,my_string)
```

Comment: Ok, in order to make this work I had to change the read mode to "r" instead of "rb". That printed what I want, now is there a way to manipulate individual integer byte values?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my initial question was phrased poorly. Really what I wanted was to read in arbitrary bytes from a file and print out a list of hex values representing those bytes. This was surprisingly difficult and the code to do it is really ugly, but it works. Here is the final code that does what I want it to do.

```
import sys

bde_file_offset = int(sys.argv[1])
bde_file_numbytes = int(sys.argv[2])

for x in range(3, len(sys.argv)):
  bde_file = open(str(sys.argv[x]),"rb")
  bde_file.seek(bde_file_offset)
  bde_file_bytestring = bde_file.read(bde_file_numbytes)
  bde_file_outputstring = " ".join("{:02x}".format(c) for c in bde_file_bytestring)
  print(bde_file_outputstring)
  bde_file.close()
```